# input as float or int

Tags: python, input, integer

I would like to be able to display double the value of any number the user inputs.

```
spam = int(input('choose any number: '))
print('Your number doubled is: ' + str(spam*2))
```

The problem is if the user inputs a decimal, ie 3.4. It comes up with an error since it becomes a float value.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#66>", line 1, in <module>
    spam = int(input('choose any number: '))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3.4'
```

Is there a simple way to let the user input any number (be it integer or float value)?

This is in python 3, so raw_input doesn't work.

Comment: Use `float` instead of `int`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `float`:

```
spam = float(input('choose any number: '))
print('Your number doubled is: ' + str(spam*2))
```

Comment: thanks! For some reason I thought float(input()) wouldn't accept an interger :/

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
spam = input('choose any number: ')

try:
        print('Your number doubled is: ' ,int(spam)*2)


except ValueError:
        print('Your number doubled is: ' ,float(spam)*2)
```

The way this works is that it will try to convert into an integer, and if that doesn't work it will convert it into a float.